# How to put a letter above another?

Tags: typography

How do I "stack" a letter above (not in front) another (in math mode)? It should look the same as binomial coefficients, just without the parentheses (which rules out `\stackrel` and `\overset`, since it makes the symbol on top smaller, as if it's tweaked superscript).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make one such command using `\genfrac`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\stackover}{\genfrac{.}{.}\z@{}}
\makeatother
```

Then use it like:

```
\[\stackover{a}{b}\]
```

Comment: It's not working. Do I need some packages for this?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović: You need `amsmath`

Comment: Yes, I'm using it, but it's still not working. As if it doesn't recognize that I've created a new command.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović: What error does LaTeX return?